# Azure cognitive service 'Content moderator' stuck in 'Failed' status

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

My service has a status of 'Failed' and I am unable to delete it.
it got stuck in the 'Failed' status and doesn't seem to be making any progress.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

We are able to create the content moderator with out any issue in the azure portal. Could you please retry, still if you are facing an issue please raise support request.

Comment: I can create new service but cannot delete the faulty service @ram-msft